# Forwarding message from group or channel

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I was trying to forward the last message from group. But I stuck on `bot.forward_message`.
Here's my code:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['update'])
def update(message):
    user_id = message.from_user
    group_id = -1001359502570
    bot.forward_message(user_id,group_id,message.message_id)
```

And I get this error:

> Bad request:message to forward not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking there [test bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/8d6970ab022680f750750e70e3e9a08eb114e560/tests/test_bot.py#L105), shows the following;

```py
def test_forward_message(self, bot, chat_id, message):
    message = bot.forward_message(chat_id, from_chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message.message_id)

    assert message.text == message.text
    assert message.forward_from.username == message.from_user.username
    assert isinstance(message.forward_date, dtm.datetime)
```

The first parameter should be the `chat_id` to forward to, not the `message.from.user`.
Try something like;

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'repeat'])
def update(message):
    send_to_id = 12345678
    user_id = message.from_user
    group_id = message.chat.id
    bot.forward_message(send_to_id, from_chat_id=group_id, message_id=message.message_id)
```

[image]